# Perfect recall but moderate precision due to imbalance?

Tags: python, unbalanced-classes, auc, precision-recall

I have a patient dataset on which I trained a RF classifier to predict whether a patient ends up in the hospital or not. Nevertheless, this dependent variable is imbalanced (66% of the patients ended up in hospital and 33% didn't).

I obtained an ROC-AUC score of ~76% which is not too bad, but when I look at the precision and recall (and the confusion matrix) there is something funny going on.

****Precision =** 0.66 &**
****Recall** = 1**

Also, looking at the predicted labels, the RF classifier predicted everyone of the test set to end up in the hospital (label 1). Is this because of the imbalance in the dependent variable (hospitalisation)? How to tackle this problem if this were the case?

Comment: So you've got a model, which just predicts a single number for everyone.  That isn't a very good model.  Can you tell us more about the data?  What are you using to predict the outcome?  How were the data collected

Comment: @DemetriPananos Yes exactly, not very useful either. I use all kinds of clinical features that are available in a health record (age, blood pressure, sodium levels etc.).

Comment: Why don't we start a little simpler and just do a logistic regression first.  How does that perform?  You can then relax the assumption of linearity using splines

Comment: @DemetriPananos I ran a logistic regression as well and got similar results. Excuse my ignorance but what are splines? I can't seem to find it in SciKit learn's logistic regression implementation.

Comment: [Splines](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/505917/perfect-recall-but-moderate-precision-due-to-imbalance?noredirect=1#comment935854_505917)  are just a different basis function.  We can use them to relax linearity.  If a logistic regression had similar results, I don't think I can help much without seeing the data.  Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handling the imbalance is worth trying; the usual techniques are reviewed here: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2017/06/7-techniques-handle-imbalanced-data.html.

Before doing that, consider changing the cutoff for class probability from its (presumed) default of 0.5. In other words, predict hospitalization only if the *P(hosp)* returned by the random forest model is greater than (for instance), 0.75 (and predict nonhospitalization otherwise), and see how that affects your confusion matrix. If you're using `sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier`, call the `predict_proba` method rather than `predict`.

And if none of these help, it may be that your input features are simply not predictive for hospitalization.

Comment: Thank you for your input! How do I change this cut-off in the RF model?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Oh sorry for not stating that. I am using Python and used SciKit-learn's implementation of a RF.

Comment: I added this information to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this suggestion. I'll explore it a bit. I currently managed to work around the imbalancing problem by setting class_weights during the hyperparameter optimisation procedure. This balances the data, however there is a risk in that. Because I think that when you visit the doctor in a hospital, the chances that you end up in the hospital are not necessarily 50/50. So would you then set this threshold based on prior expert knowledge (for example, the doctors expect that 60% of the patients that visit the department will be hospitalised and then set the predict_proba on 0.6)

Comment: No, the cutoff for `predict_proba` is not related to any prior estimate of any probability; that cutoff is simply a hyperparameter of the model, like (for instance) `max_features`. (As such, its value should finally be chosen using cross-validation - but first do some simple exploration to see if varying that cutoff helps at all.)

Comment: Do you maybe know the difference between the cut-off and class_weights?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that - they're different 'knobs' you can turn to modify the model's predictions.

Comment: I see. I'll read a bit on it. In the meanwhile I accepted your answer as most helpful and thank you for pointing me into the right direction!